# using `bytes` in python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to write a Bitcoin address validator, and I am trying to make it work with Python 2 and 3.

```
import codecs
from hashlib import sha256

digits58 = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def to_bytes(n, length):
    s = '%x' % n
    s = s.rjust(length*2, '0')
    s = codecs.decode(bytes(s, 'UTF-8'), 'hex_codec')
    return s

def decode_base58(bc, length):
    n = 0
    for char in bc:
        n = n * 58 + digits58.index(char)
    return to_bytes(n, length)

def check_bc(bc):
    bcbytes = decode_base58(bc, 25)
    return bcbytes[-4:] == sha256(sha256(bcbytes[:-4]).digest()).digest()[:4]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(check_bc('1111111111111111111114oLvT2'))
```

This code should run and print `True`. Instead, it errors on this line in Python 2:

```
s = codecs.decode(bytes(s, 'UTF-8'), 'hex_codec')
```

Error:

```
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

If I remove the 'UTF-8' part, it breaks in Python 3 instead. If I remove the call to `bytes` altogether, it breaks in Python 3.

Comment: @MarkRansom See tag wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, instead of calling `bytes`, you can `encode` directly:

```
s = codecs.decode(s.encode("UTF-8"), 'hex_codec')
```

which gives

```
dsm@notebook:~/coding$ python2.7 bitcoin.py
True
dsm@notebook:~/coding$ python3.4 bitcoin.py
True
```